# Explain all the arguments to this rec eliminator

Tags: lean, lean4, inductive-type, eliminator

I defined this inductive type for representing JSON elements

```hs
inductive JSON where
  | null
  | bool (value : Bool)
  | string (value : String)
  | number (value : Float)
  | object (data : AssocList String JSON)
  | array (elements : List JSON)
```

Which results in the following definition of `JSON.rec`:

```hs
recursor JSON.rec.{u} :
  {motive_1 : JSON → Sort u} →
  {motive_2 : AssocList String JSON → Sort u} →
  {motive_3 : List JSON → Sort u} →
  motive_1 JSON.null →
  ((value : Bool) → motive_1 (JSON.bool value)) →
  ((value : String) → motive_1 (JSON.string value)) →
  ((value : Float) → motive_1 (JSON.number value)) →
  ((data : AssocList String JSON) → motive_2 data → motive_1 (JSON.object data)) →
  ((elements : List JSON) → motive_3 elements → motive_1 (JSON.array elements)) →
  motive_2 AssocList.nil →
  ((key : String) → (value : JSON) → (tail : AssocList String JSON) →
        motive_1 value → motive_2 tail → motive_2 (AssocList.cons key value tail)) →
  motive_3 [] →
  ((head : JSON) → (tail : List JSON) → motive_1 head → motive_3 tail → motive_3 (head :: tail)) →
  (t : JSON) → motive_1 t
```

Can someone explain the various arguments that go into this? I can see that each constructor gets an argument, like church encoding of the data type, but why are there arguments for nil and cons for AssocList and List? Why 3 motives instead of 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found hints of the answer [here](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/inductive_types.html#mutual-and-nested-inductive-types)

The original definition of `JSON` "falls outside the strict specification of an inductive type" because `List JSON` and `AssocList String JSON` are not positive occurrences. As a workaround, Lean's frontend compiles `JSON` into 3 mutually recursive types:

```hs
mutual
  inductive JSON where
    | object (data : Data)
    | array (elements : Elements)
    | -- other constructors unchanged

  inductive Data where
    | nil : Data
    | cons (key : String) (value : JSON) (tail : Data) : Data

  inductive Elements where
    | nil : Elements
    | cons (head : JSON) (tail : Elements) : Elements
end
```

Lean automatically defines isomorphisms between `Data` and `AssocList String JSON` and between `Elements` and `List JSON`. Lean then uses these isomorphisms to keep `Data` and `Elements` hidden, but they're there under the hood.

The abstraction works for constructors and pattern-matching, but it leaks into the `rec` definition, which is essentially three simultaneous eliminations in one. Morally in `JSON.rec` we are defining 3 mutually recursive functions:

- `f1` : `(j : JSON) -> motive_1 j`
- `f2` : `(d : Data) -> motive_2 d`
- `f3` : `(e : Elements) -> motive_3 e`

The overall return type will come from `f1`

````hs
recursor JSON.rec.{u} :
  -- Return types for each of the three sub-functions
  {motive_1 : JSON → Sort u} →
  {motive_2 : AssocList String JSON → Sort u} →
  {motive_3 : List JSON → Sort u} →

  -- One argument per JSON constructor to handle each case in f1
  motive_1 JSON.null →
  ((value : Bool) → motive_1 (JSON.bool value)) →
  ((value : String) → motive_1 (JSON.string value)) →
  ((value : Float) → motive_1 (JSON.number value)) →
  ((data : AssocList String JSON) → motive_2 data → motive_1 (JSON.object data)) →
  ((elements : List JSON) → motive_3 elements → motive_1 (JSON.array elements)) →

  -- One argument per Data constructor to handle each case in f2
  motive_2 AssocList.nil →
  ((key : String) → (value : JSON) → (tail : AssocList String JSON) →
        motive_1 value → motive_2 tail → motive_2 (AssocList.cons key value tail)) →

  -- One argument per Elements constructor to handle each case in f3
  motive_3 [] →
  ((head : JSON) → (tail : List JSON) → motive_1 head → motive_3 tail → motive_3 (head :: tail)) →

  -- The value to fold over and the overall return value
  (t : JSON) → motive_1 t
```
````